# Any loss of security strength by using the output from hashCode() as the input to SHA256, when generating a hash of a group of objects

Tags: java, cryptography, hashcode, sha256, information-theory

I have a collection of objects, and I wish to generate a hash value (using SHA256) from this collection of objects.

This process of hashing these objects is part of a Zero Knowledge proof system, where a prover generates a proof, which is later verified by a verifier. This proof is actually the output of a hash function.

These objects all contain 3 or 4 large BigInteger values (of the order of 2048 bits). The number of objects is variable, but it will be something between 4 and 10.

I have written the following method for generating the hash value from a variable number of objects:

```
public byte[] buildHashFromHashcodes(final Object... listOfObjects) {

    for (Object obj : listOfObjects) {

        if (obj == null) {
            throw new Exception(
                "Input objects cannot be null");
        }

        _md.update(intToBytes(obj.hashCode()));
    }

    return _md.digest();
}

private byte[] intToBytes(final int intValue) {
    return new byte[] {(byte) (intValue >> 24),
            (byte) (intValue >> 16), (byte) (intValue >> 8),
            (byte) intValue };
}
```

**My question is related to the use of the hashCode method in this code. Specifically I am trying to determine whether the use of the hashCode method will weaken the security of the system, as it only generates a 32 bit number, therefore the hash is only updated with 32 bits of information during each iteration. So I am not sure if this loss of information at this point in the process really weakens the system.**

The implementation of the hashCode method of these objects uses the large BigInteger values to generate their hash codes, but the number is then truncated to an int before being return.

Part of my concerns arises from the fact that it is relatively likely that there will be collisions between the hash codes of some objects. But then again, the hash is updated several times inside of a loop, so a single collision would not be a massive problem.

Lets assume that there were 4 objects in the collection of objects. In the first iteration of the loop, 32 bits will be used to update the hash, in the second iteration another 32 bits will be used to update it, etc.

It is my understanding that the hashing algorithm is executed after the update method is called. It is not the case the 128 bits  (the 4 objects) will be stored in a buffer, and then the hashing algorithm will be executed using those 128 bits as input.

Therefore, can we say that the total number of states that the hash will be in, after the final update would be (2^32) * (2^32) * (2^32) * (2^32)? (in practices this will not happen of course, as it will be truncated at some points).

I believe that the use of the hashCode is a safe approach, given the fact that the update method is called during each iteration.

To avoid the risk of collisions between objects, an alternative approach would be to use the toString() method of each object, which returns a String that includes the full amount of entropy of each object (the value of the large BigInteger numbers is included in the String). This would mean that the hash is updated with much more information during each iteration of the loop, but I am not sure if this is necessary.

So, my question is, does the use of the hashCode method in this code weaken the strength of the system?

Comment: hashCode sucks for anything related to cryptography. You definitely don't want to use that.

Comment: Thanks. I have told that several times before. And it is generally true. And of course a hashCode does not have the same puspose as a real hash function such as SHA256. But there are circumstances when hashCode has a use (not as a hash function, but as a component in some system), and I am trying to determine if it can be used in this case without weakening the system.

Comment: @user3441604: `hashCode` definitely has a use as a hash function, just not for cryptographic purposes :)

Comment: You haven't accepted any answers bar 1 on all your questions. And the answer that you've accepted is incorrect. Could you please either accept & upvote answers or indicate what's wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 7):

This is a **terrible** idea. The purpose of a cryptographic hash function is to mix up the input data thoroughly, so that every input bit affects every output bit.

By introducing the intermediate `hashCode`s, you make it so that each input `BigInteger` only has the opportunity to affect one 32-bit hashCode. Therefore, **a collision in a single 32-bit hashCode results in a full collision on your final hash**.

Therefore, to attack your scheme, an attacker needs only find a BigInteger that has the same hashCode as *one* of your input BigInteger objects. This is totally insecure.

Comment: To be even more explicit; all the attacker has to do is precompute the SHA-256 of all 32-bit integer values (will take a few seconds), and then they'll be able to generate collisions for any given input.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do instead of calling `hashCode` - which has collisions all by itself - is to hash a *canonical* encoding in bytes. `BigInteger` has though, each number has its own unique encoding as byte array. Not all objects have such a canonical encoding though, so you cannot create a generic method for it.

Furthermore, you also need some method of keeping the values apart (e.g. 11 could be a concatenation of 1 and 1 or the number 11). The easiest way is probably to prefix the value with the size of the value.

```
public static byte[] buildHashFromSeparatedCanonicalValues(final BigInteger ... numbers) {
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("SHA-256 should always be available", e);
    }

    final ByteBuffer lengthBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE);
    for (BigInteger number : numbers) {

        if (number == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Input objects cannot be null");
        }

        final byte[] encodedNumber = number.toByteArray();
        lengthBuffer.putInt(encodedNumber.length);
        lengthBuffer.flip();
        md.update(lengthBuffer);
        lengthBuffer.clear();
        md.update(encodedNumber);
    }

    return md.digest();
}
```

This is specific for `BigInteger` values. You could make this more generic by serializing objects (that implement `Serializable`) but beware of serialization pitfalls.

Comment: And if you want to be able to parallelize above you could also implement a [Merkle tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) and hash the encoding of each `BigInteger` value separately.